# use generic keys of interface as values

Tags: typescript, generics

wanted to make something like this:

```
const { register, setValue, errors, getValues, handleSubmit } = useForm<T>();

useEffect(() => {
    options.map(option => register({ name: **keys of T**}, { required: true }););
  }, [register]);
```

for example the desired result is:

```
const { register, setValue, errors, getValues, handleSubmit } = useForm<{key1:'val1', key2:'val2'}>();
register({ name: 'key1'}, { required: true });
register({ name: 'key2'}, { required: true });
```

Is this possible if I am passing T as generic to a functional component like this ? If so how?

```
function myFunctionalComp<T>(props: Props)
```

Comment: Consider that after transpilation, no type information remains from which the runtime can deduce the correct key names. In other words, you cannot use types to help determine runtime behavior. Ask yourself how you would do this in just plain JS, then convert that solution to typescript afterward.

Comment: There are not enough details in your post to say for sure, but if you have access to an actual *value* of type `T` inside your function, you could use the `Object.keys` function to extract the key names from it. But you must have a real value to do this, you can't get it from a reference to the type `T` alone.